# SQL joins with order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.1

I have two tables with

```
table 1
col1 date
1    13/4/2014
2    15/4/2014
3    17/4/2014
5    19/4/2014

table 2
col1 date
1    13/4/2014
3    16/4/2014
6    18/4/2014

joining the two tables i should get

col1 date       col2 date
1    13/4/2014  1    13/4/2014
2    15/4/2014
3    17/4/2014  3    16/4/2014
                6    18/4/2014
5    19/4/2014
```

the important thing is the `date` columns should be sorted as can be seen for `col` data `6` and `5`.
Is this possible?

EDIT :
the final table needs to be ordered by `col1.date` and `col2.date` such that earlier date either in `col1` or `col2` will be sorted in the join table `18/4/2014` will come before `19/4/2014` even if they are in different columns. I hope i am making my point clear.
Thanks
EDIT :

```
table 1
1, "2014-04-03" 
2, "2014-04-04"
3, "2014-04-11"
4, "2014-04-16"
5, "2014-04-04"
6, "2014-04-17"
7, "2014-04-17"

table 2
1, "2014-04-04"
2, "2014-04-11"
5, "2014-04-17"
```

EDIT : after join it should be like

```
1 2014-04-03 
2 2014-04-04 
5 2014-04-04 1 2014-04-04
3 2014-04-11 2 2014-04-11
4 2014-04-16 
6 2014-04-17
7 2014-04-17 5 2014-04-17
```

Comment: Um, could we get the anticipated results table for your new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select n.col1
     , n.date1
     , m.col2
     , m.date2
from t1 n 
full join t2 m on n.date1 = m.date2
              and n.col1 = (select max(col1) from t1 where date1 = m.date2 )  
              and n.col1 is not null
where n.date1 is not null or m.date2 is not null
order by coalesce(n.date1, m.date2)
       , coalesce(n.col1, m.col2)
```

[**SQLFiddle with new data**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a646/69)

[**SQLFiddle with old data**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d2c4/62)

Comment: Joining is not the problem. order by col1, col2 will not give the desired result. please note col2 data 6 is coming before col1 data 5, as the date for 6 is earlier.
I need the data to be ordered by date across the join table.

Comment: @user1572215 : Do you mean that they should be sorted by the MAX(date) from both columns ?

Comment: yes, that is what i want to achieve. Please look at edit above

Comment: i have posted a new set of data for which this does not work. thanks for trying.

Comment: Uh still not working, check the left hand side, unsorted

Comment: @user1572215 : I misunderstood you, thought that you wanted them to be in the max order from both rows. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, now both sides are sorted in the join, but not against one another. This is not perfect for me but acceptable. Thanks once again for trying to help

Comment: @user1572215: I guess my understanding of your problem is not right.Can you post the result set that you want to get?(With the new data).Or just what id sequence it should have for both data sets.

Comment: I have done so right now. Please check with a fresh edit

Comment: If date2 in date1 then match with the last in date1. Else date2 be matched with the lower than date2 and highest date1. With these conditions date1 and date2 should also be sorted. I think now I have been able to frame the question correctly

Comment: Wow Perfect!!!!
No word to show my gratitude. Though I do not understand how it works. Perhaps a hint to explain. Thanks Once Again. Please post your sql in your answer. then i can accept it.
Thanks Again

Comment: @user1572215 : Glad to help you! I've already posted my sql query.As for hint: if there is a date2 in t2, it is merged with date1 from t1 with max id in t1 else it is pushed between the values that are the closest lower and higher values suiting date2 in t1 table.`WHERE` clause cuts off `null` values that appear when we `FULL JOIN` tables with different number of rows.Then we `ORDER BY` the first non-null columns, `date1,col1` or `date2,col2`.

Answer (score 6):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d2c4/2)

```
select col1, date1, col2, date2
from
    t1
    full outer join
    t2 on col1 = col2
order by coalesce(date1, date2), date2;
```

Comment: You may need to change to `coalesce(least(date1, date2), date1, date2)`. Otherwise `(12/4/2014 12/4/2014)` will be before `(13/4/2014 11/4/2014)`

Comment: @clodoaldo: It is not showing the correct result.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a646/1/0

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: it is not working check the fiddle with your sql. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, PostgeSQL has a wonderful function called `LEAST()`; the query is then simply:

```
SELECT col1, date1, col2, date2
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2
             ON col1 = col2
ORDER BY LEAST(date1, date2), GREATEST(date1, date2)
```

([fiddle for dataset 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d2c4/53), [fiddle for dataset 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a646/10)).

---

## EDITED

Added use of `GREATEST()` to then sort by the other value.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're referring to (you _really_ need to be more specific about what's wrong).  New version in 3, 2, 1...